# How to fix error Cannot load project: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing plugin Code Iris

Tags: android-studio

I install plugin Code Iris and he dont work for me. When i load project

> Cannot load project:
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal
>   error initializing plugin Code Iris

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are errors with this plugin and android studio, to be able to load projects you should remove this plugin first.

## Solution 1

Restart your computer this solution worked with same error with another plugin could it works with you.

## Solution 2

delete plugins directory

## Solution 3

at startup window of android studio click on configure -> plugins -> un-select this plugin from the list(this worked with me).